# Window xp 32 bits registry virtual machine strange behavior

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

I have two applications client A and service B. Both A and B are 32 bits applications and run on 32 bits window xp.
They are pretty much doing the following tasks.

1) Client A calls service B method and **service  B** to write some value in registry. 
2) Service B reads registry then do some work.

A strong behavior occurred.
For steps 1) service B writes value to registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\XX
For steps 2) it tried to read HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\xx location.

Code to sample to set registry

```
RegistryKey keyx = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegPathKey, true); 
keyx.SetValue(KeyValue, KeyData, RegistryValueKind.Binary);
```

it doesn't pass wow6432note to the path.

According to my research if 32 bits application run on 64 bits window system, it redirect registry access to wow6432note.

but in my case both applications are 32 bits and the window system is 32 bits.
How come it tried to read to wow6432note ? Any ideas? because the VM?

Anyone have experienced anything similar?

I have figure it out. our code read and write registry in two different projects and one build config is set to any CPU and another one is set to x86.

however, it does not make sense. because the op system is window 32 bits. in theory it should not read or write from 6432note at all.

Comment: have you tried stepping thru the code on your end and evaluating the variables to make sure that when you not only read, but write; that you have the correct / expected values to where it should be writing to.?

Comment: yes. and it is working correct on window 7 32 bits machine.

Comment: can you show the code logic that determines the exact writing in regards if the OS is 32bit vs 64bit how are you assigning the key in code it may help to see that then

Comment: RegistryKey keyx = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegPathKey, true);

keyx.SetValue(KeyValue, KeyData, RegistryValueKind.Binary);
it  doesn't pass wow6432note

Comment: you need to edit the original question and post it there please

Comment: My crystal ball says that you looked at the registry from the 64-bit host instead of the VM.

Comment: possible change the build config definitely fixed the issue. I don't have access the server. i am going to look at it again to figure out where i am missing. it make sense if the window xp is 64 bits.

Comment: it is a 32 bit window xp sp 3 vm